# Xamarin Forms iOS images not showing

Tags: ios, image, xamarin.forms

I have some Button with Image Property like that

```
 <Button Image="Arrow_Left_40.png" Clicked="WocheZurueck_Clicked" WidthRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

and I have that Image in Resources folder in the iOS Project but I dont see the image...

Comment: Is the build action set to the right one, `BundleResource`?

Comment: I had to give the Button a Name and in the Code Behind: ButtonName.Image = "Arrow_Left_40.png";

Comment: I tested your code and it worked well.Can you provide more information such as your picture in the assets and other codes in you project?

Comment: @jackHua its working now. I had to add "ButtonName.Image = "Arrow_Left_40.png";" into my code behind.

Comment: @Kai I mean you can use `<Button Image="Arrow_Left_40.png"/>` directly to set a image to a button. Well, adding `ButtonName.Image = "Arrow_Left_40.png` to your code behind will also work.